# Is it possible to install docker images from an offline media?

Tags: docker

We have a couple of docker images for developing API and react and next.js etc.

They all add up to about 5 GBs of storage.

Each time we setup a new machine for a new developer, we need to download all of them using `docker pull company/image` command.

Is it possible that we store them on a disk for example and install them from there?